# best way for splitting poject using git features like branching

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch

i have a project which is in bitbucket

some work/bug fix is going on in master branch

this is in both live server and test server

now client want a new feature which we should not push to live server

he want to test new feature in test server only

but at same time bug fix he has to test in test server and after that live server we have to push daily to live server for bug fix

how can i achive this using git branching/or any other git features

i am completely new to git etc
i just have coding knowledge in php/python

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your production branch is `master` and your test branch is `test`.

You can have a `hotfix` branch based on `master` too.

when you want to commit something on the test server, just commit it on the `test` branch. and when you have a bugfix commit it in the `hotfix` branch and then merge it with both `master` and `test`.

By the way, this is not the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

My answer here would be not to focus on branching strategy, but rather, a **feature flag**.

You can implement the feature *behind a flag* - then have it enabled on the test server, but disabled on the production server.

```
// pseudo-code, since I don't know which language you're using
// nor what this "feature" is!
if feature_enabled('experimental-new-thing')
  show_new_version()
else
  show_old_version()
```

There are many ways to implement this flag. The most basic would be with an environment variable. Or to be slightly more sophisticated, you can use a YAML configuration file for each environment. Or if you want even more sophisticated/advanced functionality, like partial rollout and live toggling of features, then you can look into various [third party platforms](https://launchdarkly.com/).

...Or, you can implement the flag via an "easter egg" - e.g. if this is a website, then perhaps by adding a special parameter the URL (`?secret_feature_enabled=true`), or setting a cookie.

But however you choose to go about implementing the flag, you can keep all work on a simple `master` branch - which allows developers to freely continue iterating on the feature, without worrying about how to merge a giant set of changes later down the line.

Answer (score 1):

So, you can create two main branches, like master and develop. Your live server will be on master barch and test server will be on develop branch. Then for each feature or bug fix you should create a new branch. Then merge your branch with develop branch for testing and if all ok, megre it branch with master and then remove your feature or fix branch

About naming, I usuaaly name all my feature branches like `feat-*` and bug fix branches like `fix-*`